# How to get values into twig template for fields of type Matrix in Craft CMS 2?

Tags: templating, matrix

CMS: **Craft CMS 2**

In my admin panel I have globals set called `X (under "Globals" from the sidebar and defined in` craft_globalsets `in the db from Global->Settings->New global set)`.

A field for the field layout for the global set is defined by using as Content a Field type `Y` of **Matrix type** with several plain texts fields A,B,C,...

**How do I check/show such fields' values (A, B, C, ...) in twig?**

What I have tried: I see that in the other parts of the code the handle defined in `craft_globalsets` (or equivalently in Settings->Globals) is used to fetch the globals' field value

e.g. for Globals -> set 'K' (handle in `craft_globalsets`: kHandle) there are several plaintext inputs and such are accessed in twig as:

> {{ kHandle.firstField}}

and in fact it works - but when I od the same with set X

> {{xHandle.firstFiledInTheMatrix}}

it's `null`

I have also tried to do

> {%  set matrixFields = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('Y') %}
> {{  matrixFields }}

but this returned only the field name.

Perhaps I should do something like {{ xHandle.firstFiledInTheMatrix.getMatrixContent | getFieldContent }} and a **for loop** on this? (currently guessing the function names here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get your content by using a `for` loop on your Matrix field:

```
{% for blocks in kHandle.yourMatrixfieldHandle.all() %}
    {{ block.fieldHandle }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, if you only have one block in there, you could use:

```
{{ kHandle.yourMatrixfieldHandle.first().fieldHandle }}
```